# Only address of the object is getting printed in the console on retrieving the data using hibernate and struts

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Persistent class:

```
package com.sheeba.joshua;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="DB_LEAVE")
public class DB_LEAVE {

     public String bank_id;
        public String emp_name;
        public String leaves;
        
        @Id
        @Column(name="BANK_ID")
        public String getBank_id() {
            return bank_id;
        }
        public void setBank_id(String bank_id) {
            this.bank_id = bank_id;
        }
         @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
        public String getEmp_name() {
            return emp_name;
        }
        public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
            this.emp_name = emp_name;
        }
         @Column(name="LEAVES_APPLIED")
        public String getLeaves() {
            return leaves;
        }
        public void setLeaves(String leaves) {
            this.leaves = leaves;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DB_LEAVE [bank_id=" + bank_id + ", emp_name=" + emp_name + ", leaves=" + leaves + "]";
        }
        
}
```

This is my DAO class:

```
    package com.sheeba.joshua;
import com.sheeba.joshua.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;

public class leaveDAO {
    DB_LEAVE modobj = new DB_LEAVE();
    leaveAction act=new leaveAction();
   List<DB_LEAVE> mylist;

    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction t;

    public void saveDetails(DB_LEAVE modobj){
        System.out.println("inside DAO , before query");
        mylist = new ArrayList<DB_LEAVE>();
     
        System.out.println("name" + modobj.getBank_id());
        try {
        session.save(modobj);
        System.out.println("before retrieving" +session.createQuery("from DB_LEAVE").list());
       List mylist = session.createQuery("from DB_LEAVE").list();
       for (Iterator iterator = 
               mylist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
           modobj = (DB_LEAVE) iterator.next(); }
       System.out.println("before setting to action class list" +mylist);
      
        }
        
   catch(Exception e)
   {e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("inside DAO , after query");
       
    }
```

This is my service class:

```
    package com.sheeba.joshua;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRef;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;


@ParentPackage("hibernate-default")
@InterceptorRef("basicStackHibernate")
public class leaveService extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<DB_LEAVE> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6659925652584240539L;
    leaveDAO daoobj = new leaveDAO();

    DB_LEAVE moddriven = new DB_LEAVE();
    public List<DB_LEAVE> myList = new ArrayList<DB_LEAVE>();

    public List<DB_LEAVE> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<DB_LEAVE> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }
    

    public String test(){
        return"success";
    }

    public String saveDetService() {
        System.out.println("service entry point");
       daoobj.saveDetails(moddriven); 
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public DB_LEAVE getModel() {
        return moddriven;
    }
    
    public DB_LEAVE getDb_LEAVE(){
        return moddriven;
    }
    
    public void setDB_LEAVE(DB_LEAVE moddriven) {
    
        this.moddriven = moddriven;
   }

   /* public String retrieveData() {
        System.out.println("entry point retrieve data");
        daoobj.retrieveFromDAO();
        System.out.println( daoobj.retrieveFromDAO().toString());
        System.out.println("after retrieving ");
        return"SUCCESS";
    }*/
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>LEAVE MANAGEMENT</title>
<h1>DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!! CHECK THE DATABASE...........</h1>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>BANK ID</th>
    <th>EMPNAMEE</th>
    <th>LEAVES</th>

</tr>
<s:iterator value="mylist">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="bank_id"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="emp_name"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="leaves"/></td>

    </tr>   
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

It is not printing in the JSP. earlier i was getting reference value of the object.Butnow  I am getting the values in the console as suggested by sanjeev. It worked fine. Yet the in the JSP all the values in the database are NOT iterated. Please help

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class `leaveDAO.java`, you see that only address is getting printed for the following statements:

```
System.out.println("before retrieving" +session.createQuery("from DB_LEAVE").list());
System.out.println("before setting to action class list" +mylist);
```

If you had overridden `toString()` in the class `DB_LEAVE`, you would have seen the properties of the objects getting printed.

You might overwrite the `toString()` method in `DB_LEAVE` in following manner and see the result:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DB_LEAVE [bank_id=" + bank_id + ", emp_name=" + emp_name + ", leaves=" + leaves + "]";
}
```

I think your service class i.e `leaveService.java` should have a instance level variable by name `mylist` and corresponding getter and setter method. This list should be populated from `saveDetService()` method so that you may retrieve the elements of the list from your JSP page.

Comment: I have overriden what you have said. Now in the console it is printing this way:

Comment: Could you please share `DB_LEAVE` class?

Comment: shared. Pelase see.

Comment: sanjeev, Iam gettin the values printed in the console. Would u be kind enough to let me know if the values can be printed in the jsp too? I tried iterating this using <s:iterator> tag but Im just getting some struts.xml errors. Please verify if the jsp is correct and the values from the service layer is being passed to JSP..

Comment: sheeba, can you share your error stack trace? Your JSP looks OK. The main problem is `mylist` in JSP is not being populated. Your `leaveService` class needs to send the list to the JSP. But it is not sending now.

Comment: Yes sanjeev. Solved. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah i gave.. but it says "thanks for voting.you should have 15 reputation, your votes will change to public display.."

Comment: Thanks @SheebaNancy for your effort!

Comment: Hi @SheebaNancy May I know why you un-accepted my answer?

Comment: :O I didnt Sanjeev... ?I just verified another answer also here.. duno why it got unverified fo ryou.. shud i verify only one per ques?

Comment: Yes, there can be only one accepted answer per question. Thanks Sheeba!

Answer (score 3):

What you get in console is not an address but a **reference**. When you call `System.out.println` and pass an object to it, Java doesn't know how to represent that object. So, by default, it calls the object's `toString()` method. If you don't specify your own implementation, the default one, inherited from `Object` class, prints the object's reference.

So, if you want your custom representation of the object, just override that method.

Example:

```
 public class DB_LEAVE{

   //your fields and methods
   ...

   /**
   * Returns a String that is a representation of the current object.
   **/
   @Override
   public String toString(){
     return "DB_LEAVE #" + this.id;
   }

}
```

Comment: Then the title of the question should be changed, since it's not summarizing the question. Also, the question would be too broad I think...

Answer (score 2):

You need to override [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method in DB_LEAVE class, to print the data in readable format.

By default the toString() method prints the

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

which is not a readable format.

You can override in the DB_LEAVE class as follows:-

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //Create a string with the property name and its corresponding value which is required in the logging.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the toString() method in DB_LEAVE class.

Answer (score 1):

In DAO , you have printed the list object that is why , in console it is printing the object .You want to print the object values in console or in the JSP ?

Comment: I want to print the values in the jsp

Comment: In JSP , it is printing object , if it is printing object , the just iterate and print the values.

Comment: I tried. did u see the jsp? I have tried that way. but Im only getting some unknown exception..

Comment: tyr this <c:forEach items="${mylist}" var="dbleave">
<td>
<c:out value="${dbleave.bank_id}" />
</td>
<td>
<c:out value="${dbleave.emp_name}" />
</td>
<td>
<c:out value="${dbleave.leaves}" />
</td>
</c:forEach>

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by Sanjeev, I added the getter setter for myList in the service class and thats why it was not being sent to JSP.Now its working fine. Thank you.